# Is it OK for HR to forward an email to your boss

Tags: stress

Is it ok for an HR employee to forward your email to your boss about your stress from the job?

Comment: To ask if it is OK we would have to know the country you work in.

Comment: We'll need more information before we can help. What was the email about? Did you ask for it to be confidential? Was it implied instead?

Comment: Often e-mails are considered company property so the company can do with them anything that they please (as long as no other interests are harmed). What does your contract say?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in a lot of cases, if your job is causing you stress, the only actionable thing is talking through this with your boss. But there are so many individual details that are missing that it's not really possible to say for certain.

Comment: As a general rule, never write an email that puts your boss in bad light as you never know who might forward it or who gets it. There's no guarantee that the person receiving will never forward or pass it around.

Comment: Your boss is a person, in a position, to help relieve your stress levels at work.  If they are unaware of your stress levels they cannot do anything about it.  Your boss cannot do anything about the situation if they unaware of it.  Now, if they are intentionally or unintentionally causing the stress, you should seek the advice of a trusted mentor.

Answer (score 11):

[It's been said many times here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/96977/14388), but I'll say it again:

> HR is not your friend.

They are there to protect the company. If they think they can protect the company best do that by letting your boss know, they'll do that every single time. Do not rely on HR to look after you, because they won't.

Comment: It really depends. We can not tell